# How Read the CDATA section of XML file in Android by XML parsing

Tags: android

I have to fetch the CDATA section from the XML file in my android application.

I use the SAX parser for the XML parsing,

but it skips the CDATA section, so now please tell me how I can do this.

Is there any way to read CDATA section content from XML in Android.

Comment: What you are getting in CDATA? i think HTML right, if its HTML then you can directly put the html strings inside the webview.

Comment: Can you give a link to the xml file or paste in a section of it?

Comment: http://www.bjp.org/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=12&format=raw

Comment: Yes in CDATA the HTML is include, but problem is that the parser skips the whole section inside the CDATA tab or text

Comment: I put the link to XML file, please give me Idea or code to show how I can fetch the CDATA section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devang you parsing as a DOM Parser and Try this ....for DocumentFactory and CDATA is removed and parsing is as like as Normal XML File................

**factory.setCoalescing(true);**